# Linking xcos and scilab gui for real time control of model parameters

Tags: user-interface, real-time, scilab, xcos

I am a scilab/xcos newbee. I have a model with multiple parameters I would like to change the block parameters in real time (seen on a real time graph). So I would like the functionality of the TK scale block for multiple parameters within a gui format. At the moment I have a gui which can adjust parameters, but changes to the parameters only take affect when I restart the simulation (as they are only updated once the simulation is finished running).

I have tried to use `set_param` but I am not sure it is the right tool for the job. It doesn't seem to access my xcos parameters.

Is it possible to control the parameters of an xcos model in real time with the slider and radio button functionality of a gui? How do I update my variables while the simulation is still running?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I ended up using Anylogic instead, it was able to do many of the things I wanted to do and more [here](http://www.anylogic.com/overview "here")

Answer (score 0):

SciLab/ScicosLab is certainly capable of creating interactive/responsive GUIs ( which you are refering to as "real-time"). Take a look at `uicontrol` module to learn how it should be implemented. To see some demos pleas run `demo_gui()` in the console and in the opened window go to the `GUI` section. For example:

> [image]

A nice example can be found [here](https://www.scilab.org/tutorials/how-develop-graphical-user-interface) and more examples [here](https://help.scilab.org/docs/6.0.0/en_US/uicontrol.html).

There is also the [GUI Builder](https://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/guibuilder) if you prefer a GUI drag and drop development environment